# Does hping support FTP Bounce scanning?

Tags: network-scanners, tools, scan

Does hping support FTP Bounce scanning?

I googled it, but I couldn't find its command, so I think it didn't support it.

I just find command for nmap not hping.

Comment: you would have to craft the traffic by hand in hping

Comment: So, how can I do FTP Bounce using hping?